# Fastest method to Fill Data in Nested List

Tags: performance, entity-framework, linq, ado.net

I am trying to fill a viewmodel(List) from Datatable.
Customer and WorkingTime
WorkingTime is a child List of Customer. There are several entries for a Customer.

Using Adapter.Fill Meathod

```
DataTable dtCust=GetCustomersInTable(Uid); 
DataTable dtWorking=GetAllCustWorkTimeInTable(Uid); 


var Customers = (from C in dtCust.AsEnumerable()
   select new CustomerViewModel
   {
       CustomerId = (long)C["CustomerId"],
       Address1 = DBNull.Value == C["Name"] ? "" : Convert.ToString(C["Name"]),
       Address2 = DBNull.Value == C["Address"] ? "" : Convert.ToString(C["Address"]),
       City = DBNull.Value == C["City"] ? "" : Convert.ToString(C["City"]),
       WorkingTime = GetCustWorkingTime(dtWorking, Convert.ToInt64(C["CustomerId"])),
    }}).ToList();



private List<CustomerWorkingTime> GetCustWorkingTime(DataTable dtWorking, long CustomerId)
{
        var CustomerWorkingTimes = (from C in dtWorking.AsEnumerable()
                      where Convert.ToInt64(C["CustomerId"]) == CustomerId
                      select new CustomerWorkingTime
                      {                       
                          AfterNoonFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(C["AfterNoonFrom"]),
                          AfterNoonUntil = Convert.ToDateTime(C["AfterNoonUntil"])                                       

                      }).ToList();
        return result;

}
```

I need to take whole data. It used not for displaying in UI.
This meathod is taking too much time to fill data. especially CustomerWorkingtime Filling.

Please suggest a better method to fill data.

Pagination is not possible here.

Existing setup is in EntityFramework and performance is poor.

Comment: I would remove the `AsEnumerable()`. I think that will make EF already pull the entire list into memory and then you execute your query on that rather than the DB.

Comment: DataTable class "Represents one table of in-memory data." so removins asEnumerable won't change anything. you need to change your GetAllCustWorkTimeInTable which probably pulls all the datat from Db into memory and causes the time delays. In general you shouldn't pull all data from the DB but perform as much of the queries as possible in the DB and return only the result you need

Comment: @barakcaf Only necessary data is filled in DataTable.

Answer (score 1):

Yu can try playing around with the TPL Parallel.ForEach, I think in your case this might give you a boost.

for example:

```
var Customers = Parallel.ForEach(dtCust.AsEnumerable(), c => 
   select new CustomerViewModel
   {
       CustomerId = (long)C["CustomerId"],
       Address1 = DBNull.Value == C["Name"] ? "" : Convert.ToString(C["Name"]),
       Address2 = DBNull.Value == C["Address"] ? "" : Convert.ToString(C["Address"]),
       City = DBNull.Value == C["City"] ? "" : Convert.ToString(C["City"]),
       WorkingTime = GetCustWorkingTime(dtWorking, Convert.ToInt64(C["CustomerId"])),
    }}).ToList();
```

Or in your "GetCustWorkingTime":

```
 var result=  dtWorking
                              .AsEnumerable()             
                              .AsParallel()
                              .Where(c => Convert.ToInt64(C["CustomerId"]) == CustomerId)
                             .Select(c= >  new CustomerWorkingTime
                             {                       
                               AfterNoonFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(C["AfterNoonFrom"]),
                               AfterNoonUntil = Convert.ToDateTime(C["AfterNoonUntil"])                                       
                      }).ToList();
```

you should try them separately, and together, to see which one gives you the best performance (depends on the size of the tables).

**Note:** using both together might cause problems since in "GetCustWorkingTime" you'll end up iterating over the same table by multiple tasks in the same time.